# How does fsnotify setting affect system performance?

Tags: files, filesystems, inotify, intellij

Occasionally a software package I install complains that the default fsnotify setting is far too low for decent performance. Intellij IDEA or crashplan are two examples.

They suggest using fsnotify value several orders of magnitude than the default value and I follow the suggestions.

How come the default value is so low when it doesn't seem to make a lot of difference when you set it to some very high value like 512000 and is there a maximum value?

Can very high values on large file systems cause problems? I'm struggling to find any information about how to tune this setting.